# Bi-Directional References are always fetched Doctrine MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

Symfony2 Project with Doctrine MongoDB ODM:

I have the following documents:

**User**

```
referenceOne:
    my_buddy:
        targetDocument: Buddiness #(just an example)
        mappedBy: from_user
        simple: true
    buddy_with_me:
        targetDocument: Buddiness
        mappedBy: to_user
        simple: true
```

**Buddiness**

```
referenceOne:
    from_user:
        targetDocument: User
        simple: true
        inversedBy: my_buddy
    to_user:
        targetDocument: User            
        simple: true
        inversedBy: buddy_with_me
```

On every authenticated request I have 2 extra queries:

```
db.Buddiness.find({ "from_user": ObjectId("...") }).sort([ ]).limit(1).limit();
db.Buddiness.find({ "to_user": ObjectId("...") }).sort([ ]).limit(1).limit();
```

How can I get rid of these 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually doctrine should use [lazy-loading](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-lazy-loading) by default.

But i think you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519314/1832745).

Remove the `mappedBy` attribute.

Comment: It's not as simple as a solution: if you remove the mappedBy you are also de-normalizing the value.
Now if you delete the mapped object you have to remember to delete also the reference. I've found that a better way is to use referenceMany, and force the setter to have only 1 value